# Execute commands with pdsh

Tags: 14.04, command-line, cluster

I'm trying using pdsh to execute a bash script across all my nodes, but pdsh will not allow me to `cd` into directories and also does not allow me to execute python `bash: python: command not found`. How do I address this?

Comment: You might want to use ansible instead.

Comment: So probably `python` isn't installed on your nodes. What OS and version do they have? Please add the output of `pdsh -a grep -F "VERSION="  /etc/os-release` to your question. You may anonymize the hostnames if they are somehow "secret".

Comment: ubuntu 16.04 and I get this error when I try that above `pdsh@smpl: /etc/genders: error opening genders file`